# How to remove a line that match a pattern with sepific occurance?

Tags: bash

Here i would like to delete the line that match with
 `<li><p><a href="anti\/recent.html">` with the fourth occurance

I asked here before but that is a bit different, at that time i only have to match  with `<ul>`

at that time i get the answer:

```
    awk '/<ul>/ {ul++} ul == 6 { getline } 1' file
```

However , that can not be applied to  `<li><p><a href="anti\/recent.html">`
as i tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

```
awk '/<li><p><a href="anti\/recent.html">/ {lipa href="anti\/recent.html"++} lipa href="anti\/recent.html" == 4 { getline } 1' file
```

That return me synatx error . Can any one give some help ?? thanks

---

The errors are:

```
awk: /<li><p><a href="anti\/recent.html">/ {lipa href="anti\/recent.html"++} lip                                                                                                                               a href="anti\/recent.html" == 4 { getline } 1
awk:                                                 ^ syntax error
awk: warning: escape sequence `\/' treated as plain `/'
awk: /<li><p><a href="anti\/recent.html">/ {lipa href="anti\/recent.html"++} lip                                                                                                                               a href="anti\/recent.html" == 4 { getline } 1
awk:                                                                                                                                                                                                                 ^ syntax error
```

***Continue:
Thanks for anyone that helped
the awk here seems have some bug

```
^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I<li><p><a href="anti/recent.html">4 Jul 2011 - Fraudulent email purporting to be related to Standard Chartered Bank (Hong Kong) Limited</a></p></li>$
                                      <!--<li>There is no phishing attack at this  moment.</li>-->$
^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I    </ul>$
```

it will delete the `</ul>` as well although that is on the different line?

I have edit it and test:

```
#!/bin/bash
i=1 cat test2.html | while read -r
do
    if [ "$(echo $REPLY | grep -E '<li><p><a href=\"anti/recent.html\">')" ]
    then
        let i++;
        if [ ! "$i" -eq 4 ]
        then
            echo "$REPLY";
        fi;
    else
        echo "$REPLY";
    fi;
done > test2.html;
```

is this correct or not???  when i execute the code and see the result of test2.html, it is a page with nothing??? no html code no text? thanks .

Comment: Are you saying you want to delete the fourth occurrence of your string?

Comment: yes , of a string that match with<li><p><a href="anti\/recent.html">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must do it with awk? If not - this code may be more clear.

```
i=1 cat some_file | while read -r
do 
    if [ "$(echo $REPLY | grep -E '<li><p><a href=\"anti/recent.html\">')" ]
    then 
        let i++; 
        if [ ! "$i" -eq 4 ]
        then 
            echo "$REPLY"; 
        fi;
    else
        echo "$REPLY";
    fi;
done > fixed_file;
```

Comment: echo means actually print the result on the shell?

Comment: Yes - this script reads line by line and then outputs everything but 4th match of that string ("\s*" means there may be any spacing on that line before or after that string). $REPLY is reserved variable when using "read" - it contains line that was read if no other variable was specified. Btw, are you sure that there are both back and normal slashes in "anti\/recent.html"?

Comment: thanks, but can it delete that line instead of just displaying it?

Comment: of course the link is formatted , that should be anti/recent.html only

Comment: i=1 cat test2.txt | while read -r
do 
    if [ "$(echo $REPLY | grep -E '<li><p><a href=\"anti\/recent.html\">')" ]
    then 
        let i++; 
        if [ ! "$i" -eq 4 ]
        then 
            echo "$REPLY"; 
        fi;
    else
        echo "$REPLY";
    fi;
done > fixed_file;

i have adjusted a bit

Comment: You see that last "> fixed_file;" in the end? This script outputs nothing - it reads from "some_file" and writes into "fixed_file" (replace them with real names).

Comment: will it delete the line that match the fourth occurance?

Comment: Edited post to match "anti/recent.html". Yes, it shoudl delete that line. You can check it with "diff" command or by hand.

Comment: can i not adding ^ and $ in your script?

Comment: actually my  html code is like that:
<li><p><a href="anti/recent.html">some Content</a></p></li>
if i use something like:
^<li><p><a href="anti/recent.html">$ 
it won't match anything

Comment: Edited my post - should work now. Or do you want to delete only '<a href="anti/recent.html">' - not whole line?

Comment: sorry i just copy whole the code you gave me and the output file is a white page with nothing???Are there something i have missed?

#!/bin/bash
i=1 cat test2.html | while read -r
do
    if [ "$(echo $REPLY | grep -E '<li><p><a href=\"anti/recent.html\">')" ]
    then
        let i++;
        if [ ! "$i" -eq 3 ]
        then
            echo "$REPLY";
        fi;
    else
        echo "$REPLY";
    fi;
done > test2.html;

Comment: You can't read and write to the same file. Chose some temporary file to write to and then just move it in the place of your main file. For example replace/add "done > test2.html;" to "done > _test2.html; mv _test2.html test.html;". If that didn't help just remove "> test2.html" in the end of script and look at output in console.

Comment: thanks it works but i would like to know why it deletes it??Since if that is not equal 4, echo it,  if equal 4,  that stills echo it

Comment: No, there are two levels of "if". First one checks if line matches your string - if not just do nothing with that line (output it). If it matches then it increases "$i" counter and outputs line if "$i" is not equal to 4 - so only 4th entry of matched line will not be outputted.